Repacking or printing unpacked Lua tables
Why does the table.unpack() function print the unpacked table only if there is nothing following the function?
> print(table.unpack({1,2,3}))
1       2       3

> print(table.unpack({1,2,3}),"a")  -- expecting: 1       2       3       a
1       a

> print("a",table.unpack({1,2,3}))
a       1       2       3

Background:
I am trying to create a recursive function that unpacks a table, inserts a value, and repacks it to return a table with the new value. This works when you do something like table.pack("a", table.unpack({1,2,3})) but not when you do table.pack(table.unpack({1,2,3}), "a").

I once fell in the same trap.

When a multires expression is used in a list of expressions without
being the last element, or in a place where the syntax expects a
single expression, Lua adjusts the result list of that expression to
one element.

Lua 5.4 manual. 3.4.12 – Lists of expressions, multiple results, and adjustment.
So, table.unpack(…) or ... should be last in a list of expressions.
Perhaps, if you literally want to insert some values into a table, you could use table.insert()?

It looks like table.insert() is the way to go, though I am still not sure why table.unpack() is set up to have to be last. This requires the function to have mutable elements, albeit for a theoretically short amount of time.
 local function recursive_insert(x, n)
   if n == 1 then return  {x} end

   local l = table.pack(table.unpack(recursive_insert(x, n-1)))
   table.insert(l, x)

   return l
 end



@4a6166: That's just the way value lists work. It's not table.unpack's fault. My guess is that making them more flexible would make the syntax too complicated, or it would be to difficult to implement.

When multiple values are returned, they are put in consecutive registers, and it's impossible to know how many. So if there were some more call arguments after the multiret expansion, it would be impossible to statically (at compile time) know in which registers to put them. They could have used *x (like python) or ...x (like JS ES6), but in fact it's impossible to impllement it because of how the stack, registers and bytecode is designed. Technically it would have been possible for table construction but not calls. They probably didn't do the former either for consistancy.

Deep unpack table:
function unpackAll(...)
    local args = {...}
    local result = {}

    local function unpackNested(tbl)
        for _, v in ipairs(tbl) do
            if type(v) == "table" then
                unpackNested(v)
            else
                table.insert(result, v)
            end
        end
    end

    unpackNested(args)
    return table.unpack(result)
end

Example:
print(unpackAll({1,2,3},"a"))
1   2   3   a

